# Kuratowski measure of non-compactness of unit ball and unit sphere.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, compactness

Let X be any metric space. Let $\mathcal{M}_X$ denote the class of all bounded subsets of a metric space $X$.

**Definition:**

- Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space. The function $\alpha:\mathcal{M}_X\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ with $(k = 1, 2, . . . , n\in\mathbb{N})$, s.t.
  \begin{eqnarray*}
  % \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
    \alpha(Q) &=& \inf\{\epsilon > 0: Q\subset \bigcup^n_{k=1}S_k, S_k\subseteq X, diam(S_k) <\epsilon\}\\
    &=& \inf\{\epsilon>0: \text{$Q$ may be covered
  by finitely many sets of diameter }\leq\epsilon\}
  \end{eqnarray*}
  is called the Kuratowski measure of non-compactness.

**Question:** If X is infinite dimensional, how to show that
$$\alpha(B_1(X))=\alpha(S_1(X))=2$$
where $B_1(X)$ and $S_1(X)$ are the unit ball and unit sphere in X , respectively.

Comment: I can't see why it's  to  exactly? why not 4 ..?